# Microsoft Graph API Subscriptions endpoint provides @odata.nextLink that gives a 404

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm currently experiencing an issue with the subscriptions endpoint.

When making a call to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions, a next link is returned.

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#subscriptions",
    "@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions?$skiptoken=NPt3S7g2KIxJBA0KWwQetRhFtPT2ht6ZVYoisBCCtvlN2050CZg8WeNGnmaMqUn.....",
    "value": [
...
...
```

When following this next link, most of the time, more results and another nextLink should be provided until all the data has been returned.

However for the last two days we have been experiencing issues where following this link has led to the final link giving a 404 response and some html with the following body.

```
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>404 - File or directory not found.</h2>
  <h3>The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Is this a known issue with the service, or is there a process that should be being followed differently here?

I have been able to replicate this in Postman as well as impacting the java sdk [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java).

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 2021-10-13, this issue is no longer occurring and the Graph API is once again functioning as expected.

Comment: Happens for me again, do you also experience it?